# how to update child node in fire base by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After completing auth in firebase I want to store data in a simple array in the firebase database and my crud operation is working fine by using JavaScript. But I want to add a child array. I'm a beginner in firebase please help me to get this solution.

```
import { getDatabase, ref, query, orderByChild } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const db = getDatabase();
const auth = getAuth();

const myUserId = auth.currentUser.uid;
const topUserPostsRef = query(ref(db, 'items/' + myUserId), orderByChild('starCount'));
```

Comment: none of the code you shared reads from or writes to the database, so it's hard to say what isn't working about it - or how to expand it to write a child array. Can you edit your question to show what code you've already created to [write the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I find another way to figure it out but still facing some errors. When I fix I will definitely update it.